# How to switch between small and full screen view for video just like youtube does

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I am using video view for playing video in list view now on clicking on full screen button i want video view to cover whole screen and start playing from same point where it was playing lastly. And aging on clicking button it should return to list and play video from same point. In short i want to use a single video view and want to make it full screen and small screen as user taps the button.same as you tube does for playing video.
Please any one help me in this situation I am badly stuck in this.

[image]

Comment: You could just save the position

Comment: @MarcoAcierno it means I have to pass that position to another video view on full screen activity???

Answer (score 0):

Keep the instance of your video view saved,  where you have the entire screen allocated to video view in landscape mode.

Keep different layout for your portrait and landscape mode.

Override the function onConfigChanges to provide the same instance of the video view you had saved, and pass it on to the video view in the other layout.

Make sure your activity is not re-created when orientation is changed by adding the following lines to your activity in manifest:
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"

And when orientation changes to landscape mode, use the following lines to allow the activity to take the entire space on the screen:

```
 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
 getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```